# Why won't my unity controller work properly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity and I am facing problems with the animator controller component.

When pressing on Z button, my player is supposed to start moving forward, but the animation won't start.

Here is my code :

```
public Animator anim;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Z))
    {
        anim.SetFloat("MoveX",0.17f);
        Debug.Log("hhh");
    }
    else
    {
        anim.SetFloat("MoveX", 0);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
    {
         anim.SetFloat("MoveZ",0.208f);
         Debug.Log("stiw");
    }
    else
    {
        anim.SetFloat("MoveZ", 0);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
    {
        anim.SetFloat("MoveX",-0.166f);
    }
    else
    {
        anim.SetFloat("MoveX", 0);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        anim.SetFloat("MoveZ",-0.2f);
    }
    else
    {
        anim.SetFloat("MoveZ", 0);
    }
}
```

Moving backward and starting right works properly, except moving forward and moving to the left

Here is a screenshot of my blend tree

[image: blend tree]

Comment: you misspeled your setfloat in the keycode.z it should be MoveZ not MoveX

Comment: nope ive triyed it but nothing happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well look at your conditions in `Update` again and think what happens if you press the forward button (Q):

- first you set `anim.SetFloat("MoveZ",0.208f);`
- **BUT**: this means that you are **not** pressing backwards (D) so you set `anim.SetFloat("MoveZ",0);`

see it now? The last two checks overrule the first two and "eat" you input ;)

---

You should make your cases more exclusive like e.g.

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Z))
    {
        anim.SetFloat("MoveX",0.17f);
        Debug.Log("hhh");
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
    {
        anim.SetFloat("MoveX",-0.166f);
    }
    else
    {
        // Only reached if neither Z nor S is pressed!
        anim.SetFloat("MoveX", 0);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
    {
         anim.SetFloat("MoveZ",0.208f);
         Debug.Log("stiw");
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        anim.SetFloat("MoveZ",-0.2f);
    }
    else
    {
        // Only reached if neither Q nor D is pressed!
        anim.SetFloat("MoveZ", 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: But what does else if means ?

Comment: See [if - else if - else](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else) .. the conditions are basically checked in the order they are written in the code. If the first condition is true, the others aren't even checked. If the first condition is false, then the second (if else) is checked etc .. finally if none of the previous conditions matches the `else` handles any other possible cases